# How to insert a list of values to a tree using Map function?

Tags: functional-programming, tree, ocaml, binary-search-tree

So, I have a tree with the definition:

```
type ('k, 'v) avlnode =
  | Leaf
  | Node of int * 'k * 'v * ('k, 'v) avlnode * ('k, 'v) avlnode
```

And a function to insert values to the given tree.

```
let rec set (n : ('k, 'v) avlnode) (key : 'k) (value : 'v) : ('k, 'v) avlnode =
  match n with
  | Leaf -> Node (0, key, value, Leaf, Leaf)
  | Node (h, k, v, left, right) ->
      if k = key then Node (h, k, value, left, right)
      else if key < k then Node (h, k, v, set left key value, right)
else Node (h, k, v, left, set right key value)
```

What I'm trying to do is write a function to insert a list of values to the tree using Map. what I have for now is this piece of code.

```
let add_all (n : ('k, 'v) avlnode) (keys : ('k * 'v) list) : ('k, 'v) avlnode =
  let new_set (key : 'k * 'v) : ('k, 'v) avlnode = set n (fst key) (snd key) in
  let mutated_nodes = List.map new_set keys in
  match List.tl mutated_nodes with [] -> Leaf | f :: l -> f
```

The problem with the function is that it inserts each value to the initial tree rather than a new mutated tree.
How do I write this function in order for me to have a tree with all the values in the list?

Comment: You should use `List.fold` instead of `List.map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to elaborate on the comment of @Lee:

The type of `List.map` is: `('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list`. Just from the type alone you can see that it can only return a list of values. Each value in the output list is the result of applying a function to one of the values in the input list. There is no way `List.map` can return a tree, which is what you want.

To put this another way, `List.map` is useful only for the narrow purpose of transforming one list into another based on a simple rule that applies separately to each element of the list.

The fold functions `List.fold_left` and `List.fold_right`, on the other hand, are much more general functions that can perform almost any desired computation that needs to work with each of the elements of a list in turn. That's the situation you're in, so that's what you should use.